# Using the For statement to create buttons and add them to a panel?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel

I've tried a couple of ways to do this...Basically I'm trying to create a tic tac toe board for an assignment and maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I get a "not a statement" error when I try to create the buttons. Here's the code I've got:

```
        int rows = 3;
        int cols = 3;
        JPanel ticTacToeBoard = new JPanel();
        ticTacToeBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                JButton gameButton[i] = new JButton[];
                ticTacToeBoard.add(gameButton[i]);
            }
        }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your array somewhere:

```
JButton[] gameButton = new JButton[size];
```

Then in your loop:

```
gameButton[i] = new JButton();
```

For example:

```
JButton[] gameButton = new JButton[rows * cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        gameButton[i] = new JButton();
        ticTacToeBoard.add(gameButton[i]);
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at the [Java tutorial on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Note: Is there a reason why you don't use a `List` instead of an array? If would make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks that helped... Teacher wants an array.

Answer (score 4):

The following is incorrect

```
JButton gameButton[i] = new JButton[];
```

There is no need for the []. Just do

```
JButton gameButton = new JButton();
ticTacToeBoard.add(gameButton);
```

If you want to store the buttons in an array as well, you should have code like

```
JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[10];//or whatever length
...
JButton gameButton = new JButton();
buttonArray[i] = gameButton;
```